# CodeIgniter: How To Do a Select (Distinct Fieldname) MySQL Query 

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, distinct

I'm trying to retrieve a count of all unique values in a field.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT count(distinct accessid) FROM (`accesslog`) WHERE record = '123'
```

How can I do this kind of query inside of CodeIgniter?

I know I can use `$this->db->query()`, and write my own SQL query, but I have other requirements that I want to use `$this->db->where()` for. If I use `->query()` though I have to write the whole query myself.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

```
$record = '123';

$this->db->distinct();

$this->db->select('accessid');

$this->db->where('record', $record); 

$query = $this->db->get('accesslog');
```

then

```
$query->num_rows();
```

should go a long way towards it.

Comment: In my code the solution was     $this->distinct();

Answer (score 12):

try it out with the following code

```
function fun1()  
{  
   $this->db->select('count(DISTINCT(accessid))');  
   $this->db->from('accesslog');  
   $this->db->where('record =','123');  
   $query=$this->db->get();  
   return $query->num_rows();  
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also run **`` ->select('DISTINCT `field`', FALSE) ``** and the second parameter tells `CI` not to escape the first argument.

With the second parameter as `false`, the output would be **`` SELECT DISTINCT `field` ``** instead of without the second parameter, **`` SELECT `DISTINCT` `field` ``**

Answer (score 5):

Since the count is the intended final value, in your query pass

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('accessid');
$this->db->where('record', $record); 
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return count($query);
```

The count the retuned value

Answer (score 5):

***Simple but usefull way:***

```
$query = $this->db->distinct()->select('order_id')->get_where('tbl_order_details', array('seller_id' => $seller_id));
        return $query;
```