# How to prevent duplicate through grouping two columns? MYSQL/Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a predicament where I'm trying to make a facebook-style wall where you have the wall table, users table, wall post table and images table (for this scenario). To simplify the process, the image is posted in the images table, and an entry is made as a wall post. It groups by wall id but when comments are made, it repeats the wall post for every new comment. Essentially I just want ONE post per wall post.

**MYSQL Query (Codeigniter):**

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('wall_posts AS p');
    $this->db->join('users AS k', 'p.wall_poster = k.user_id AND p.wall_owner = k.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->group_by('p.wall_id');
    $this->db->where('p.wall_poster', $pid); // $pid = given user id
    $this->db->or_where('p.wall_owner', $pid);
    $this->db->order_by('p.wall_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit($lim); // $lim = limit number

    return $this->db->get();
```

**Table example**

```
    wall_id|owner_id|reference_id|wall_poster
    1      |0        |55         | 2
    2      |0        |30         | 1
    3      |0        |32         | 2
    4      |2        |19         | 3
    5      |0        |0          | 4
    6      |0        |0          | 2
    7      |0        |32         | 3
    8      |0        |18         | 4
```

Now, you can see that ID 3 and ID 7 has the same reference_id (image in this case), so later when the result is displayed, any posts referencing that image will be displayed multiple times instead of just once. I also have a column called post_type to help afterwards in the controller which determines if it's a normal post, comment, an image post, comment of an image etc...

Thanks ahead of time! This is bugging me to no end and I'd like to keep this as a single query if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try `select distinct`, but you'd need to narrow it down to just that field.  In other words, try something like this:

**Edited for codeigniter method for `distinct()`**

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select ('reference_id');
$this->db->from('wall_posts AS p');
$this->db->join('users AS k', 'p.wall_poster = k.user_id AND p.wall_owner = k.user_id', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('p.wall_id');
$this->db->where('p.wall_poster', $pid); // $pid = given user id
$this->db->or_where('p.wall_owner', $pid);
$this->db->order_by('p.wall_id', 'desc');
```

Alternately you could try:

```
$this->db->select('DISTINCT(reference_id)');
```

Comment: Thank you, I will learn about distinct and give it a try. Will let you know if it worked :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I've tried in many different variations of select('distinct', '`column`') and distinct('column') but none seem to work. There aren't many google results but those that do talk about it claim that distinct is fairly buggy at least with codeigniter.

Comment: don't put `distinct` into quotes.  The way that it works within normal sql is like this:  `select distinct reference_id`  or you can put backticks on `reference_id`.    However, according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/656710/3044080  in codeigniter, it might work a little different.  I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you for your response but it's not returning any results, presumably because select('reference_id') is only specifying reference_id instead of ('*'). But making it select all doesn't change the results, and putting distinct right before group_by as another answer suggested did nothing. Mind you i do add the join alias. I'm looking back at the logic and it seems fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Distinct *should* return results, but only once for  each reference id.  (try it directly in your database, and you'll see what I mean) The reason why `*` returns all the result is that all of your rows (as shown above) are already distinct.  While you may have reference id twice, you have different entries for wall_poster, so it returns each combination.  Note, there are several other methods that should work for codeignighter on that link I provided above;  I just was providing only one method.  I'll add another one.

Comment: The instructions are here in the manual:  https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late reply. After thinking on what you said, I realized that all I really needed was a parent_id column to sort it all since obviously the new messages in no way could relate to the original without it. I tested distinct on another test page and it worked just as you said it did.  Thanks a lot, it was a great learning experience :)