# Group By with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, group-by

I use CodeIgniter for my project and this is my code in model

```
public function group_all_ville(){  
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('departement');
        $this->db->join('villes', 'villes.num_dept = departement.num_dept');
        $this->db->group_by('nom_dept'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        return $query->result();
    }
```

and this is error after execution

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1055

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'pneu.departement.id_dept' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

SELECT * FROM `departement` JOIN `villes` ON `villes`.`num_dept` = `departement`.`num_dept` GROUP BY `nom_dept`

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/pneu/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

I try different method but nothing result. Thanks

Comment: It seems rather odd that you are using a `GROUP BY` clause and `SELECT *`.  GROUP BY is most appropriate when you want to use aggregate function (e.g. `SUM()`, `COUNT()`, etc) in your `SELECT`.  This question shows code and an error message, but it fails to include table schemas, sample input, and the desired output. The absence of a [mcve] makes the question Unclear.  I have to assume that you are seeking unique `nom_debt` values, but if that is the case, there are better ways to isolate `DISTINCT` rows.

Comment: ...actually, based on the OP's self-answer, this looks like the appropriate dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/656622/2943403

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `order_by` clause as well

```
$this->db->group_by('nom_dept'); 
$this->db->order_by('nom_dept', 'asc');  # or desc
```

---

> **FYI :** Setting SQL mode and Session set is not fix the actual error.

Examples (**Better not to Do**)

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35729681/4595675

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

```
$this->db->select('d.nom_dept');
$this->db->from('departement AS d, villes as v');
$this->db->where('v.num_dept = d.num_dept');
$this->db->group_by('d.nom_dept');
```

Refer to [*12.20.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I encountered this problem also when the system migrated to mysql8.0. Since, there are many queries which involved grouping. I used the code without changes on mysql config file. If you don't want to disable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY you can review your query individually.  [SO explain it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

```
$this->db->query("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', ''));");
```

Comment: Please make more of an attempt to explain how your snippet works and why researchers should use this versus other techniques.  Please be more generous with your insights.

Comment: Disabling isn't a good way to resolve the problem. See [Why should not disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824498/why-should-not-disable-only-full-group-by/64831540#64831540)