# Interacting with MySQL 5.1 database from computer with MySQL 8 via python/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-5.1

I just updated my system from Ubuntu 19.1 to 20.02 - and it looks like all the previous MySQL settings got wiped out.

Current system has MySQL 8 (server + client) installed.
The server I am trying to access has MySQL 5.1.

Every time I try to connect using SqlAlchemy, I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake
```

From what I read - this error happens because the server I'm attempting to connect to is running version of MySQL that is too old.

Is there a way to downgrade MySQL connector, to fix the connection issue?

Comment: looks like
 pip show mysql-connector-python   gives me version of connector.  now need to try to switch it to earlier version .  lets see if this works.

Comment: Also consider having a database migration plan. Your state of stretching a developed app via a old connector and and older database will hamper your use of new features.

Comment: @danblack  this has definitely encouraged us to migrate :-[  unfortunately, without much prep or plan.

Comment: We ended up migrating. Few things to keep in mind in going from 5.0 (ish) to 8: 1) GROUP BY has change (stricter)   2) login pw is sha2 encryption

Comment: So I hope you considered the queries rather than disabling [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824498/why-should-not-disable-only-full-group-by/64831540#64831540). I'm assuming the caching_sha2_password just required a later connector version again.

Comment: yup, updated everything to newer version.  hopefully this will last another 5 years :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make this work by uninstalling newest connector:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall mysql-connector-python
```

Then installing an older version of the connector:

```
sudo pip3 install -Iv mysql-connector-python==8.0.5
```

To check your connector version, you can use:

```
pip3 show mysql-connector-python
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. Add the parameter `use_pure=True` in your call to the `connect()` function.

From version 8.0.11 and up this option is **False** by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to an older installation like MySQL version 5.0.67 from a newer Python installation like Python version 3.8.10 then to stop ERROR 1043 (08S01): Bad handshake, do the following to downgrade the connector:

1. Uninstall whatever mysql-connector-python you had installed either using an msi file or pip install. For example

   py -3 -m pip uninstall mysql-connector-python-x.x.x
   or
   if it was an msi installation, uninstall it from the control panel – programs and features
2. Next download a zip file of older mysql-connector-python e.g. mysql-connector-python-2.2.2 (You’ll find the list on the Archives tab on https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)
3. Unzip the file to a directory e.g. If your python installation is on the root of drive C, unzip the mysql-connector you downloaded on C:\python such that you have the resulting folder structure C:\python\ mysql-connector-python-2.2.2
   (You can do this on the downloads folder if you please)
4. Now  open the DOS prompt using “Run as administrator” and navigate to  C:\python\ mysql-connector-python-2.2.2 (or whatever version you downloaded)
5. From there, run the following command

   py -3 setup.py install

This worked for me on windows 7 OS. Logically, you can make it work for you on other operating systems.