# How to write inner join query instead of writing multiple select statements in my sql

Tags: mysql

I have written a query using  `SELECT` statement for fetching the data form two tables and query is working fine but it is taking more time to execute and fetch the data (in each table contains only 40k rows) I'm new to  Database logics or query's in  `MY SQL`

This is how I written a query in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a_sno AS UID,a_name AS `Name`,a_emailid AS EmailID, 
            a_mobile AS Mobile,a_othermobile AS Broker_Mobile,
            a_vendorname AS Broker_Name,a_planname AS Subscription_Plan, 
            a_createdtime AS Date_of_Registration, 
            a_plandatetill AS Subscription_End_Date,
            CAST(
                IFNULL(
                    (SELECT a_amount 
                    FROM details_payments 
                    WHERE a_status='success' 
                    AND a_uid=ll.a_sno 
                    ORDER BY a_sno DESC LIMIT 1)
                ,'-') 
             AS CHAR) AS Subscription_Amount,
             CAST(
                IFNULL(
                    (SELECT a_confirm_time 
                    FROM details_payments 
                    WHERE a_status='success' 
                    AND a_uid=ll.a_sno ORDER BY a_sno DESC LIMIT 1)
                ,'-')
             AS CHAR) AS Date_of_Subscription,
             CAST(
                IFNULL(
                    (SELECT a_registerednotsub_rmks 
                    FROM whatsapp.details_remarks 
                    WHERE a_uid=ll.a_sno 
                    ORDER BY a_sno DESC LIMIT 1)
                ,'-')
             AS CHAR) AS Remarks
-- ,IFNULL((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM details_payments WHERE a_status='success' AND a_uid=ll.a_sno),'') AS total_count_payments
     FROM details_login ll 
     WHERE ll.a_createdtime BETWEEN "2022-05-09" AND "2022-06-14" 
     AND ll.a_activated = 1 
     AND (ll.a_planname = 'Free Trial' OR ll.a_planname = '-' OR ll.a_planname = '')
     AND(a_fyersid != '-' 
         OR (a_fyersid = '-' 
             AND ll.a_mobile !='0' 
             AND ll.a_mobile != '' 
             AND ll.a_mobile !='-'
             AND LENGTH(ll.a_mobile) = '10' 
             AND ll.a_mobile != '6666666666' 
             AND ll.a_mobile != '7777777777'
             AND ll.a_mobile != '8888888888' 
             AND ll.a_mobile != '9999999999' 
             AND (a_mobile LIKE '6%' AND LENGTH(a_mobile) = '10')
             OR (a_mobile LIKE '7%' AND LENGTH(a_mobile) = '10') 
             OR (a_mobile LIKE '8%' AND LENGTH(a_mobile) = '10') 
             OR (a_mobile LIKE '9%' AND LENGTH(a_mobile) = '10')
         )
      )
      ORDER BY a_sno DESC) jjjjj 
      WHERE Subscription_Amount ='-' 
      GROUP BY Mobile;
```

And I want to write this query using `inner join`

Can anyone suggest me how to write.

Comment: For performance issues you should publish the table definitions so we can see what indexes you have in place and an explain so we can see how the optimiser thinks it should be done.

Comment: Why you have order by on fk in sub queries in list fields? You can remove it and take the first

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://learnsql.com/blog/converting-subqueries-joins/

Answer (score 0):

Without an understanding of the structures and relationships between your tables, and the explain output for your query, it is not possible to suggest how you should rewrite your query. But there are some things which jump out as obvious issues.

As already pointed out by @JoeTaras, your ORDER BY clauses in the sub queries serve no purpose, as all rows returned will have the same value for `a_sno`, meaning the value returned by each of the sub queries is unpredictable. Perhaps they should be ordered by the pk in descending order?

Your outer query -

```
SELECT *
FROM () jjjjj 
WHERE Subscription_Amount = '-' 
GROUP BY Mobile
```

is relying on [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) being disabled. [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824498/why-should-not-disable-only-full-group-by#64831540) to another question for a simple explanation of why you should have it enabled. Your current query gives indeterminate results.

The `Subscription_Amount ='-'` WHERE clause is not applied until after the inner queries have been materialized in full. This is an unnecessary overhead when the same criterion can be applied with a LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS on the inner query.

```
...
FROM details_login ll 
WHERE ll.a_createdtime BETWEEN "2022-05-09" AND "2022-06-14" 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM details_payments WHERE a_status = 'success' AND a_uid = ll.a_sno)
...
```

Your main set of criteria for `a_mobile` is repetitive and probably does not behave as you intended. I suspect, to achieve your intended functionality, you need to place another pair of parentheses around the last four OR'ed criteria, and the length check can be removed as it is already performed earlier in the list of criteria. The first three `a_mobile` criteria can be removed as they are covered by the length criterion -

```
        OR (ll.a_fyersid = '-' 
            AND LENGTH(ll.a_mobile) = 10
            AND ll.a_mobile != '6666666666' 
            AND ll.a_mobile != '7777777777'
            AND ll.a_mobile != '8888888888' 
            AND ll.a_mobile != '9999999999' 
            AND (
                ll.a_mobile LIKE '6%' OR
                ll.a_mobile LIKE '7%' OR
                ll.a_mobile LIKE '8%' OR
                ll.a_mobile LIKE '9%'
            )
        )
```