# Duplicated result for Codeigniter join

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is my **Model** codes on [avasam](https://avasam.ir) :

```
$this->db->select('*,orders.id AS order_id');
  $this->db->from('orders');
  $this->db->where('orders.user_id',$userId);
  $this->db->join('products', 'products.id = orders.product_id');
  $this->db->join('payments', 'payments.user_id = orders.user_id');  
return $this->db->get();
```

in `result array` i have duplicate for all raw !

and this is my **profiler** for `db query` :

```
0.0004      SELECT *, `orders`.`id` AS `order_id`
FROM `orders`
JOIN `products` ON `products`.`id` = `orders`.`product_id`
JOIN `payments` ON `payments`.`user_id` = `orders`.`user_id`
WHERE `orders`.`user_id` = '24'
```

Now i don't need duplicate data's . what's my wrong ?

Comment: `select distinct`

Comment: @jarlh thanks but `distinct` not worked , i used `$this->db->group_by('order_id');` and now worked fine and duplicates gone

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656622/codeigniter-how-to-do-a-select-distinct-fieldname-mysql-query

Comment: @jarlh i tested but not working !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve by adding only this :

```
$this->db->group_by('order_id');
```

For unknown reasons `$this->db->distinct();` Not woked