# Codeigniter :fetch records which have unique email

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

i am trying to fetch records that have unique email address ( there are repeating emails as well in the database)

below is my query but it prints all the records

```
$this->db->distinct('email'); 
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('booking');  
$query =    $this->db->get(); 
$data['booking']=$query->result();
```

Please help me to fix the issue . Thanks

Comment: You are using distinct wrong.  See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656622/codeigniter-how-to-do-a-select-distinct-fieldname-mysql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: How To Do a Select (Distinct Fieldname) MySQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656622/codeigniter-how-to-do-a-select-distinct-fieldname-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your results in two ways: `distinct` and `group_by`

For reference, please [view](http://www.technofunctionalmama.com/how-to-use-distinct-to-get-distinct-records-in-codeigniter/) here

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('booking');
$this->db->distinct('email');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

You can use `group_by` as alternatives way in your active record query.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->group_by('email');// add group_by
$query = $this->db->get('booking');
return $query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this...

```
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('booking');
  $this->db->group_by('email');
  $query = $this->db->get(); 

  $data['booking']=$query->result();
```

it will echo all unique email addresses except those duplicated email.