# how to populate drop down list from mysql database and should don't repeat values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I populate drop down list from mysql database and it shouldn't containt repeated values.

I try to use distinct keyword but failed to use. What is the logic I should use?

Example:
I have two bsc and two Bachelor in Mechanical in dropdown option and I want to display one bsc and one dropdown and similar for other course.

My codeigniter query is not working properly. The dropdown option is selected dynamically. How to solve it?

This is my controller

```
$courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered.course_offrd_name');
$data['collg_id'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
if (empty($data['collg_id'])) {
  $data['collg_id'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
} else {
  $courserecord = $this->front->get_data_wheree('tbl_course_offered.course_offrd_name');
  $data['collg_id'] = json_decode(json_encode($courserecord), True);
}
```

This is my view file

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <select name="course_offrd_name" id="course_offrd_name" onchange='' class="form-control ui fluid dropdown">
        <option value="">Select Course</option>
        <?php foreach($coursedata as $val)
      {
      ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $val->course_id?>" <?php if(isset($course_offrd_name)) { if($course_offrd_name==$val->course_id) { ?>selected
          <?php } }?> >
          <?php echo $val->course_id;?>

        </option>
        <?php }?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my model file

```
function get_data_wheree($table,$where)
{
  return $this->db->distinct($table,$where)->result();
}
```

This is table file or structure
 [image]

This is my frond end dropdown option
 [image]

Comment: In your SQL query, add `DISTINCT` before `id` field.

Comment: @Pupil how to add DISTINCT before id field.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/656710/1841760

Comment: @Pupil how to do it in my code ..where i m wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by on cat_id to get unique value. As per you attachment cat_id is also repeated and same for respective course_id.

```
function get_data_wheree($table,$where)
{
  $this->db->group_by("cat_id");
  return $this->db->get($table,$where)->result();
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::group_by()

Comment: @DiwakarYadav I was edited my query. Please check it